# Cauchy inequality and infinite series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of complex numbers. Prove that:
$$\left|\sum_{n,m=1}^\infty a_n \overline{a_m}\right|\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|^2$$
I think that it is true because of *Cauchy inequality*. But I'm not sure about that because so far I have seen this inequality only for *finite series*.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality you ask about is false (probably you just copied the problem wrong).

For example, say $a_1=a_2=1$ and $a_n=0$ for $n>2$. Then $\sum_{n,m=1}^\infty a_n\overline{a_m}=4$, while $\sum |a_n|^2=2$.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe I have copied the problem wrong. What is the Cauchy Inequality for complex numbers and infinite series?

Comment: $|\sum_na_n\overline{b_n}|\le(\sum|a_n|^2)^{1/2}(\sum|b_n|^2)^{1/2}$. (Meaning that if both sums on the right are finite then the sum on the left is finite and satisfies the inequality.)

Comment: Then $|\sum_n a_n\overline{a_n}|\le(\sum|a_n|^2)^{1/2}(\sum|a_n|^2)^{1/2}=\sum|a_n|^2$?

Comment: Yes, except that's silly - in fact $\sum_n a_n\overline{a_n}$ is _equal_ to $\sum|a_n|^2$. I don't think you can figure out what the problem actually was by guessing...